# smooth movement of the button - hover css

Tags: html, css

I made a site for a discord bot, with a beautiful and smooth button. The problem is that because of the line `transition: 3s;` the button when opening the page smoothly moves from the top-left corner to the center. How to fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>scp-bot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="title">
        <span id="scp">SCP</span><br>
        <span id="db">Discord bot</span>
    </div><br>
    <div id="butDiv">
    <a id="but" href="">Пригласить</a>
    </div>
    <div id="htu"><span></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
#scp{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 130px;

    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#db{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
#but{
transition: 3s;
font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size: 60px;
border: 5px solid #fff;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 10px 20px; /* Поля */
text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
color: white; /* Цвет текста */
left: 50%;
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
background: black;
margin-top: 1%;
}
#but:hover{ background: white;
    border: 5px solid #0000;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 80px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);     
    transition: 3s;

}
```

The button should be in the center, but when you open the site, it "flies" there and does not appear there initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly
try to add this:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        document.getElementById("but").classList.remove("notran");
    });
</script>
```

and this css class

```
.notran
{
    transition: 0 !important;
}
```

and this for the button

```
<a id="but" class="notran" href="">Пригласить</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer with a question but I haven't got the reputation yet to comment.

Could you explain what it is exactly that you want?

Do you want the button on the left or in the center when the page loads?
What do you exactly want to achieve with the hover effect?

I will edit this answer when you've responded.

Answer (score 0):

Only transition the properties that you want to change on hover.

```
#but {
    transition: background 3s, border 3s, color 3s, box-shadow 3s;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 20px; /* Поля */
    text-decoration: none; /* Убираем подчёркивание */
    color: white; /* Цвет текста */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: black;
    margin-top: 1%;
 }
 #but:hover { 
    background: white;
    border: 5px solid #0000;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 80px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }
```

You also don't need the `transition` property in the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean page transition? Use @keyframes will animate page on load.
Adding this in css :

```
@keyframes slideFromLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

And modify your css on `*` like this :

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    animation: slideFromLeft 2s;
}
```

Try to load your page.